# How to format txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, formatting, format

I am trying to convert a txt file into a csv file in Python. The current format of the txt file are several strings separated by spaces. I would like to write each string into one cell in the csv file.

The txt file has got following structure:

UserID Desktop Display (Version) (Server/Port handle), Date

UserID Desktop Display (Version) (Server/Port handle), Date

etc.

My approach would be following:

```
with open('licfile.txt', "r+") as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(" ") for line in stripped if line)

with open('licfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(('user', 'desktop', 'display', 'version', 'server', 'handle', 'date'))
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Unfortunately this is not working as expected. I do get following ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. Additionally only the intended row headers are shown in one cell in the csv file.

Any tips on how to proceed? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add an input and an expected output example please?

Comment: You should include the input and output of the script (or some part of it).

Comment: Just use ```read_lines = in_file.readlines()``` before ```stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)``` to read the lines in the buffer before iterating over them. Otherwise, the logic of the code seems good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the built in `csv` module to accomplish this easily:

```
import csv

with open('licfile.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('licfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter=" ")  
    writer = csv.writer(out_file, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

I used `lineterminator='\n'` argument here as the default is `\r\n` and it ends up giving you an extra line of return per row in most cases.

There are also a few arguments you could use if say quoting is needed or a different delimiter is desired: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
with open('licfile.txt', 'r') as in_file, open('licfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.strip():
            out_file.write(line.strip().replace(' ', ',') + '\n')
```

and for the german Excel enthusiasts...

```
...
    ...
        ...
            ... .replace(' ', ';') + '\n')
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This solution at least writes the data into the csv but unfortunately writes everything into one column, I would like to separate each record from the others.

Comment: What do you understand by column? It puts commas inbetween all entries where were spaces before. If you define _column_ by _what-is-put-in-different-columns-when-I-load-that-csv-with-Excel_ then you should have a look what Excel uses as column separator. You're in Germany? Try `;`...

Comment: Yes (not only, but also) in Germany the standard decimal sign is a comma, which is unfortunately exactly the same character which is used as a column separator in  - well, _comma separated value_ -files. Therefore the column separator is here a semicolon. This is part of the locale preferences topic with software in general.

Comment: You guessed right, thanks for the explanation. Now if I have got several rows in the txt file with equivalent columns, can I simply add that after every date a new row shall be started?

Comment: Yes, all records are printed in one line but I would like to have one row per entry in the text file.

Comment: Alternatively, you could be using quotes `""` to identify items with `,` in it.  The module `csv` would be helpful for this scenario.

Comment: @Krrr Correct, that's a solution for using the same character for decimal sign and column separator. However, in this case here we came from the other direction, which is a german standard Excel installation, which is set to use `;` as column separator - so this topic had to be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

You are using comprehension with round brackets which will cause to create tuple object. Instead of that just use square bracket which will return list. see below example:

```
stripped = [line.strip() for line in in_file]
lines = [line.split(" ") for line in stripped if line]
```

Comment: No sorry, but this is simply wrong. round brackets with a for-expression result in a generator, not in a tuple. and even though OP probably did that by accident, this is imo not the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

```
licfile_df = pd.read_csv('licfile.txt',sep=",", header=None)
```

Comment: @shaikmoeed I think there's some misunderstanding - spaces are the separators in the source file. Target file should be a csv, which by standard is generally comma separated. AFAIU this is in fact the main conversion which the whole post is about...

Comment: using pandas it is so easy to convert text file into DataFrame and sep="," is for if your text file is seprated by comma , It varies according to your text file.

Comment: Yes, correct it's easy from usability point of view. But on the one handside it might be a little too heavy library for a simple task like this and then this post is simply not tagged with pandas...